# InfoPath user roles issue

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-server

I am facing some weird issue when creating an InfoPath 2010 form and I am pretty sure that its a silly mistake which I am not able to solve it. Here's the step by step process on how I'm creating it

1. Opened the blank form and changed the settings to "InfoPath 2010 filler form". Created the user role called "Group 2 Role" and added a user name in it.
2. Created 2 views "Group 1 View" and "Group 2 View". Clicked on "Form Load" and made a rule that when user's current is equal to "Group 2 Role" then switch to "Group 2 View"
3. I published it and when I go to InfoPath library and click on "Add document" option it trows an error saying that "This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath"

I am using MS Office 2013 and publishing the form on an SharePoint 2010 site. I'm not sure what's missing here, so please help me!

Comment: I cannot use browser based forms because user roles are not supported in them

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: @Gwny I use IE 9 running on Win7